# Assigning dynamic value to variable

Tags: shell, variables, dash-shell, dynamic-values

how can I assign a *dynamic value* to variable? The simplest method I know about is by using a *function*. For example

```
fn(){
    VAR=$VAL
}
VAL=value
fn
echo $VAR
```

will output

```
value
```

but I want something simpler, like

```
VAR=$VAL
VAL=value
echo $VAR
```

to output

```
value
```

What command should I use? Preferably to be compatible with *dash*.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Removed *#!/bin/sh* in connection to *dash*. Thank *"Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams"* for the explanation!

**UPDATE 2:** Adding the source for my script to better understand the situation.

```
INPUT=`dpkg -l|grep ^rc|cut -d' ' -f3`
filter(){
    echo *$A*
}
for A in $INPUT;do find ~ -iname `filter`|grep ^$HOME/\\.|grep -iz --color $A;done
```

This script should help finding the remaining configuration files of removed packages.

Comment: `/bin/sh` isn't dash on my system.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I know `/bin/sh` is called _dash_, while `/bin/bash` is called _bash_.

Comment: On my system `/bin/sh` is bash.

Comment: `/bin/sh` can point to a great many different programs. They're expected to share some common core behavior. Dash is one such program (which happens to conform to the core more closely than bash does, when `/bin/sh` points to bash).

Comment: OK, I checked that and my `/bin/sh` is linked to _dash_.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if function is not good, then maybe calling eval is okay?

```
export VAR='echo $VAL'
VAL=10
eval $VAR
```

This will display

```
10
```

Comment: I'll rather stay away from _eval_. As I previously mentioned, it represents a security hole for the system.

Comment: How about export VAR='expr $VAL + 0' instead? expr will fail in case of VAL other than a number....

Comment: The _value_ should be in a form of _text_ combined with _another variable_.

Comment: I mean _value_ as a value of a variable, not as a mathematical expression.

Comment: I do not want to be quick in stating that then it is not possible, but I doubt it is. echo $VAR will take the 'textual' form of $VAR and simply display it. Because of that I think it is not possible without either setting VAR before, or evaluating it by eval. I will be looking at your thread to see if there is someone else that finds a way. Take care!

Comment: I also think that isn't possible, but I thought I ask at least. Who knows, maybe there is someone who know something that I don't.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple function that sets value?

```
# export is needed so f() can use it.
export VAR

f() {
    VAR=$@
}

f 10
echo $VAR
f 20
echo $VAR
```

The code above will display:

```
10
20
```

Comment: I wanted to do it without using a function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs, you want an *indirection*, so try the following shell code (tested with `dash`) :

```
var=foo
x=var
eval $x=another_value
echo $var
```

**output** :

```
another_value
```

**finally**:

Each times you need to modify `var`, you need to run `eval $x=foobar`

Comment: I read somewhere that _eval_ is not a good choice, because it presents a security hole. Therefore, I rather use a function for this.

Comment: With some shells (bash), you can use `declare` instead.

Comment: I know about that, but as you said it work only with _bash_, which is generally slower than _dash_. I'll rather use a _function_ for this.